# Ionic CLI add platform is reading from the wrong config.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run `ionic platform add android` - but when it runs, it uses a config.xml from an entirely different project on the same computer.

Is there some kind of cache or project switching I need to do to make sure it is reading form the right xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please build with following:

> 1. cordova platform add android
> 2. cordova build android

you can use cordova while installing platform in ionic project because Ionic internally use cordova itself.

Please feedback me if error still persist.

**UPDATE:**

Please make fresh directory and generate project over there as you mentioned  in your comment that's issue occurred  because with config.xml there are others bunch of files. please generate new project in completely new directory resolved your problem Glad to help you.

Thank you

Comment: Hey I'm getting the same issue. It's as if it remembers the project it was working on and tries to build from the same previous config.xml again.

Comment: try with complete new project of ionic at time of add platform and build use cordova instead of ionic.

Comment: Just tried that - sorry - the same problem happens. It's telling me "Error: Platform android already added." because it still thinks I'm in the other project. Really strange.

Comment: remove ionic, cordova from your system and add again latest one, finger crossed...

Comment: and also try to make new project in fresh directory like create new one D:/IonicTest/ and create new project in this directory and try again.

Comment: Okay - figured it out.
The issue was that in the folder that contains all my projects - somehow there was a config.xml and a bunch of other files. Once I got rid of those it worked.
Happy to let you update your answer and upvote it :-)